# Increasing space between plot labels

Tags: r, pie-chart, label, plotrix

I am plotting a 3D pie chart using `pie3D` from `plotrix` package:

```
dev.new(width=6, height=5)
pie3D(weights, radius = 0.8, labels=paste(names(weights), labels, sep = "\n"), explode=0.05, mar=c(4, 4, 4, 4), border = F, col = my.col, main="Asset Allocation", labelcex = 0.8, shade = 0.5)
```

and I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, the labels are on top of each other. I tried modifiying the `mar` input (margins), but it doesn't quite work. Would there be a way to increase spacing between the labels on the graph, so that it is less jammed? Please keep in mind that I want the radius of the graph to stay fixed at 0.9

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever downvotes the question must think that the answer is obvious. Could you please then provide a constructive answer instead, or at least an explanatory comment as to why the downvote? A simple -1 is anything but constructive

Comment: I did not downvote, but since you made the same comment on your last (deleted) question, you should be aware that there are many other reasons to down vote a question besides someone thinking that it's "obvious". (In this particular case, pie charts, not to mention 3D pie charts, are sure to attract some haters. They are terrible, terrible things.)

Comment: Well, in the context of asset allocation, it serves the purpose..

Comment: Besides the distaste for pie charts, especially ones that are pseudo rotated, the is also a distaste for questions that are posed with no data.

Comment: I didn't think data was relevant in this case. I am assuming there is an option in the function `pie3D` that does the trick, and was hoping for a hint on that, and actual data is not related to the display of labels at all! As for the graph itself, there is nothing more relevant than a pie chart for asset allocation.

Comment: The only thing that is worse than a pie chart for data visualisation is a 3D pie chart.  This type of visualisation gives unequal visual weight to equal components.  Try a stacked bar chart instead, for example.

Comment: To my eye, the 8% for Agriculture as a thin triangle has less visual impact (ie appears smaller) than the 7% for Intl.Developed.Equities as a thick triangle. Add the visual impact of the pie sides which are only visible on the near items and you get a seriously bad graphic. Stop it now. [No reason to downvote though]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `pie3D.labels`. E.g.:

```
library(plotrix)

vec <- sample(1:10)
labs <- paste('piece \n no', 1:10, sep = " ")

par(mfrow = c(2,1))
a <- pie3D(vec, radius = 0.8, explode = 0.05, mar = c(1,1,1,1))
pie3D.labels(a, radius = 0.8, labels = labs, labelcex = 0.7)

b <- pie3D(vec, radius = 0.8, explode = 0.05, mar = c(1,1,1,1))
pie3D.labels(sample(seq(0, 2*pi, 0.1), 10), radius = 0.8, labels = labs, labelcex = 0.7)
```

The plot:

[image: pie3d]